# redis official docker image port exposure to windows

Tags: docker, redis

I am completely new to docker. I want to run the official redis docker image on my installed docker engine on my windows 10 machine and access it from applications run on windows.

I have installed the image 
https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/

and use the command

> "docker run --name some-redis -d redis"

to load the image and run the container successfully

but still port 6379 is not accessible from windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The port is only exposed. That means that it will be avalible to linked containers (or to all containers in docker-compose). To publish the port (make it available outside docker) you use `-p host_port:container_port` like `-p 6379:6379`

Comment: I already tried this..but when i telnet the port from windows, I always get connection refused, I have tried to change host_port to be 6380 or any other number but in vain

Comment: Did you use `docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis && telnet localhost 6379`? That should work

Comment: That wa my command "docker run --name some-redis -d redis -p 6379:6379"..but I will give it another retry

Comment: the args after the image name (redis) are appendend to the redis process (redis -p 6379:6379 will be called). Put the -p before redis and it will work